# Communicating information between threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a thread that reads the memory of another program. The information read is stored in a global variable. I, then, create another thread that acts on this information.

I have initialized the variable to be 0. After the first thread is created (the one that reads the memory of another program), it prints to console the value it read (it successfully reads the value correctly). In my main function, though, it still prints out to be zero.

I've tried std::atomic, but that won't work for this instance. How can I get my variables to have changes accepted despite not being in the same thread?

Here is how I create threads:

```
std::thread tTest( [ & ]
{
    TestFunction( );
} );
vecThreads.push_back( move( tTest ) );

std::thread tTest2( [ & ]
{
    OtherTestFunction( );
} );
vecThreads.push_back( move( tTest2 ) );
```

Here is an example of what I do in main:

```
int bob = 0;

int main( )
{
    CreateThreads( );
    if ( bob )
    {
        std::cout << "T2 bob: " << bob << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "T2 bob: uninitialized" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

My test functions:

```
void TestFunction( )
{
    ReadProcessMemory( hProcess, lpBaseAddress, &bob, sizeof(bob), 0 );
    std::cout << "T1 bob: " << bob << std::endl;
}

void OtherTestFunction( )
{
    if ( bob )
    {
        std::cout << "T2 bob: " << bob << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "T2 bob: uninitialized" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This isn’t the problem, but you don’t need those lambdas. Just pass the address of the function you want the thread to call.

Comment: `bob` is a local variable inside `main`. There’s no other `bob` defined in the code, so the uses of the name `bob` outside of `main` are not legal. Post real code.

Comment: Pete, sometimes my functions take parameters, and this is just so much easier that doing it the other way :p - as for the "real code", this is really all you need. The other stuff just over complicates it like replace Bob with a class, and that class inherits other classes, defines other objects, etc.

Comment: a little unrelated to your problem but having T2 polling the variable isn't an effective way to use your CPU cycles. IMHO it would be better to signal the T2 thread *when the value changes* in other cases T2 could just wait. check out  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

Comment: "The other stuff..." is where the problem is. Nobody can tell you how to change that **local variable** without knowing how the rest of your code gets at it. And, no, you can't replace `Bob` with a class, because `Bob` has not been defined anywhere. Post real code.

Comment: "sometimes my functions take parameters" -- fine, but nobody here is looking at **that** code; the code you **posted** doesn't take parameters, and **simplifying** the code means **removing** irrelevant details like extraneous lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some sort of thread synchronization.  There is no guarantee that `TestFunction` will run before `OtherTestFunction`; it all depends on how the OS schedules threads.  And in this case, `ReadProcessMemory` is not a quick function.  `OtherTestFunction` will usually complete running before `TestFunction` gets a value stored into `bob`.

For example, you could use `async` (from `<future>`) to create your first thread (that runs `TestFunction`).  Pass (via move) the `future` you get from `async` to your second thread (`OtherTestFunction`), which would wait on the future for the first thread to finish executing.  Then it could access the value of `bob`.

You could also look at `std::promise`, or you could use the `CreateEvent` and related functions in the Windows API.

Comment: I've tried doing a 10 second wait after the first thread, still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

A very simple and elegant solution to your problem is this:

First declare a global variableL `std::mutex mut;`

Then in your functions do this:

```
void TestFunction( )
{

    mu.lock();
    ReadProcessMemory( hProcess, lpBaseAddress, &bob, sizeof(bob), 0 );
    std::cout << "T1 bob: " << bob << std::endl;
    mu.unlock()
}

void OtherTestFunction( )
{
    mu.lock();
    if ( bob )
    {
        std::cout << "T2 bob: " << bob << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "T2 bob: uninitialized" << std::endl;
    }
    mu.unlock();
}
```

If you need to make sure one function runs before the other create another global variable like this: `bool firstRan`.

Then in your methods do this:

```
void TestFunction( )
{

    mu.lock();
    ReadProcessMemory( hProcess, lpBaseAddress, &bob, sizeof(bob), 0 );
    std::cout << "T1 bob: " << bob << std::endl;
    firstRan = true;
    mu.unlock()
}

void OtherTestFunction( )
{
    while(!firstRan) {}
    mu.lock();
    if ( bob )
    {
        std::cout << "T2 bob: " << bob << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "T2 bob: uninitialized" << std::endl;
    }
    mu.unlock();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: aw man, the whole point was to have one thread constantly reading memory and the other thread just acting on whatever the latest information was. i guess I can work with this though. hopefully there are some other solutions :o

Comment: It is impossible to read and write with memory at the same time @J.Doe

Comment: well we're not reading and writing to the same memory at the same time, it's more like we have a variable that I want all threads to be able to see. As of right now, no one can see it. it just shows 0